# mysqldump guarda las vistas como tablas

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Al realizar un DUMP con mysqldump, las vistas se guardan como tablas:

CREATE TABLE `v_facturas`

Lo correcto sería CREATE VIEW `v_facturas` AS...

¿Qué opción debo utilizar para que no suceda este problema?

Comment: He probado de varias formas y siempre se convierten las vistas en tablas. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Sí, pero al restaurar el DUMP, se crean tablas y no vistas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creando un `dump` de prueba, muestra como efectivamente se crea una estructura temporal (table) de la vista, que luego se elimina para crear la vista final:

```bsh
--
-- Temporary table structure for view `v_facturas`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `v_facturas`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v_facturas`*/;

/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `v_facturas` (
  `id` tinyint NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;

--
-- Table structure for table `facturas`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `facturas`;

CREATE TABLE `facturas` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Final view structure for view `v_facturas`
--

/*!50001 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `v_facturas`*/;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v_facturas`*/;

/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50001 VIEW `v_facturas` AS select `facturas`.`id` AS `id` from `facturas` */;
```